# can we connect data source to more than one on premises database in power bi

Tags: powerbi

Any Power BI expert here?  I need little help in the on-premises data gateway? I am developing a reporting model for an IT firm in the UK. the firm is offering online booking services in the dental field through a portal. the company has 300+ customers. I have created a model report that has two Data sources.

1. the local database of customer
2. portal

the data gateway is working fine if I publish a single report per customer and publish it to power bi web services.
Is it possible to connect a single report to an on-premises data gateway(standard mode) to 300+ customers local servers where I can differentiate them using Row Level Security? or do I need to publish a single report for every customer on the web services?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to more than one on-premise data source/database using the gateway, in this use case maintaining over 300+ connection in a Power BI file and data gateway will be exceptionally difficult (mostly impossible). As you have 300 connections you cannot use Row Level Security to define which customers see which connection and table, it is a filter ON an object, not a filter OF objects

I would recommend, pulling the data into a single database and structure then using that database as a single source, using SQL Server Integration Services (if you are using SQL Server) or other Extract/Transform/Load (ETL) tools. You can then use Row Level Security on that table to filter data to the correct customer.

Comment: Nicely explained.